# JavaScriptSerializer: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mono, xamarin-studio

What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

string json = "{\"numbers\":[{\"one\":\"1\"},{\"two\":\"2\"},{\"three\":\"3\"}]}";
dynamic dictionary = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
Assert.AreEqual(3, dictionary["numbers"].Count);

System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToObject (IDictionary`2 dict, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType (System.Type type, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToList (System.Collections.ArrayList col, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType (System.Type type, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToObject (IDictionary`2 dict, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType (System.Type type, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType[Object] (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[Object] (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Just one thing that I don't get: why are you using the dynamic keyword there, it bring no benefit in your case.

Comment: and if you look at this line: "at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToObject (IDictionary`2 dict, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0", the error seems to be related when converting to the dictionary. Did you try using the static type instead just to narrow the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not make `Dictionary<string, object>` work, I've decided to drop it and use static types instead. BTW, [this online tool](http://json2csharp.com/) is quite handy for generating C# classes from JSON.

Answer (score 2):

As I see no problems with your code, apart from the use of the count property, and since the code is breaking when the json is being deserialized, I would advise you to use the static type definition instead, just to narrow the changes of problems with your code:

```
        string json = "{\"numbers\":[{\"one\":\"1\"},{\"two\":\"2\"},{\"three\":\"3\"}]}";
        var dictionary = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Maybe just maybe there is an issue with using dynamic types with the JavaScriptSerializer and if there is indeed a problem with the JavaScriptSerializer you can always report that to MSFT.

Comment: Using `<Dictionary<string, object>>` over `dynamic` still gives me the same error :(

Comment: I tried that code myself and if does work properly, and even if the JSON was not valid you would get a different exception. I've got not clue what the problem is then. Is that piece of code being use by multiple threads? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: There's nothing special about this code, I'm reproducing the issue with a simple NUnit test case. Now I'm using Xamarin Studio 4.0, I wonder if Mono's implementation is buggy or whatever.

Comment: Ok that says it all, yes I would say that mono has an implementation problem, I thought you were using .Net (windows)